# sql field value is contained by string

Tags: php, sql

I have a table in my database with the structure something like that:
`ID`,`category`,`county`,`keyword`

Now I have the category, the county and some text.

I want to take from my database the rows with the category, county that I have, BUT also the `'keyword'` must be in my text

```
select from `posts` where `category`='$category' and `county`='$county'
```

Can anyone help me with the third condition (`'keyword'` must be in my `$text`)?
Thank you!

Comment: Your query is not correct as it should be `select * from` try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the text of column `keyword` should be contained anywhere in the $text variable, then use

```
select ID,category,county,keyword
  from `posts`
 where `category`='$category' and `county`='$county'
   and '$text' like concat('%', `keyword`, '%')
```

Actually, to prevent SQL injection, it would be better to use a prepared statement using parameters for `$category`, `$county`, and `$text` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i want, but it doesn't work. I think the syntax is the problem. I will search further

Comment: @Andreea What do you mean by " it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Which?

Comment: this is the error message:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ `keyword` +'%' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: @Andreea Sorry, I used Microsoft SQL syntax, not MySQL syntax. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @FlankPl Maybe you can help me with another query. I have a table `projects`. In this table there is a row `categories` where are all the categories_id where a the project is. For example a project is in category 1 and 2, so the row value is **1,2**. What I want is to count all the projects in a category. So I try this: `select * from projects WHERE '{$id_cat}' IN (categories)` , but it does not count the projects that have more than one category. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Andreea This seems to be completely unrelated to this question. I would suggest to as a new question.